# Unreal Engine version for smooth performance on HP 15s eq2144au with Ryzen 5 processor?

Tags: performance, game-development, hardware, amd-processor, unreal

I am using an HP 15s eq2144au laptop, which is equipped with an AMD Ryzen 5 processor. I want to use Unreal Engine on this device, but I'm unsure about which version would provide the best performance, ensuring smooth and clear functionality.

What is the most suitable version of Unreal Engine for my laptop? I want to ensure that I choose the appropriate version that works optimally with the hardware specifications of my device.

Furthermore, if anyone has experience using Unreal Engine on a similar laptop or processor, I would greatly appreciate any feedback or advice.

Comment: Please don't post same text multiple times. Also, StackOverflow is not a discussion forum, you should ask a single clear question -- not ask for comments about different situations people might have ran into.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Shouldn't you be concerned about how the game runs on the customer PCs, not just your PC?

Answer (score 0):

The version of the engine doesn't really matter, you should rather look at :

- light management (Static or Mobile, Shadows, Reflections, Shaders render)
- reduce logic calls (avoid tick calls)
- textures quality
- polygons counts in your models

There are others ways to improve performance but you have a start point.